# Xcode - set different class for run and test actions

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working on iOS app (using Objective-C and Xcode) and for now I am trying to set different class for run action and for test action and cannot achieve it so far.
Lets imagine there is target **A** and also target for unit test, lets call it **A_UnitTest** (**A_UnitTest** tests target **A**).
There is class responsible for login process lets call it **LoginManager** which has method login and this method is responsible for login to real system. There is also class for fake login with the same name and the same interface as **LoginManager** and it should serve only for testing purposes.

During run action target **A** has real **LoginManager** class connected and all is working pretty well, but during test action (when **A_UnitTest** is selected) and I run unit tests - I want to test target **A** I would like using fake **LoginManager**. I can manually select fake **LoginManager** for target **A** (deselect real **LoginManager** and select fake **LoginManager** for target **A**), but I would like to have it working automatically. I mean I would like just select target **A_UnitTest** and test target **A**, but during testing I would like fake **LoginManager** should be used instead of real **LoginManager**. Do you know if I can somehow do this in Xcode? Or should I put some script in pre-action step?

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that what you are trying to achieve is possible (at least easily).
What you should do, is to structure your code in a way that dependecies can be injected, and then you can use mocked versions of your production classes in tests.

Simple example (in Swift, since no language tag) :

Production :

```
protocol LoginManagerProtocol {
    func loginWithCredentials(login: String, password: String)
}

class LoginManager: LoginManagerProtocol {

    func loginWithCredentials(login: String, password: String) {
        // perform your production login here
    }
}

class LoginViewModel {
    private let loginManager: LoginManagerProtocol

    init(loginManager: LoginManagerProtocol) {
        self.loginManager = loginManager
    }

    func loginUser(with login: String, password: String) {
        loginManager.loginWithCredentials(login: login, password: password)
    }
}
```

Tests :

```
class LoginManagerMock: LoginManagerProtocol {

    var mock_loginWithCredentials: ((String, String) -> Void)?
    func loginWithCredentials(login: String, password: String) {
        mock_loginWithCredentials?(login, password)
    }
}

class LoginViewModelTests: XCTest {

    func test_loginUser_shouldPassCredentials_toLoginManager() {
        // Arrange
        let sampleLogin = "login"
        let samplePassword = "password"

        let loginManagerMock = LoginManagerMock()
        var capturedCredentials: (login: String, password: String)?

        loginManagerMock.mock_loginWithCredentials = { login, password in 
            capturedCredentials = (login, password)
        }

        // Act
        let sut = LoginViewModel(loginManager: loginManagerMock)
        sut.loginUser(with: sampleLogin, password: samplePassword)

        // Assert
        XCTAssertEqual(sampleLogin, capturedCredentials.login)
        XCTAssertEqual(samplePassword, capturedCredentials.password)
    }
}
```

If you are using Objective-C, similar approach could be used, or you could use one of mocking libraries (for example [OCMock](http://ocmock.org/)).